# Javascript - Use regex to find multiple occurrences of a pattern in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in this format

```
"{{abc}}, {{def}}, some text {{ghi}}, some other text {{jkl}}"
```

And I would like to replace each of `{{...}}` with some string based on what is `...` (that comes out of json and not an issue) and stuck with what regex pattern to use. Closest I could come was to `/{{(.*)}}/gi`, but that returns the whole string as the same has `{{` and `}}` at ends. Here's the code I have tried

```
let str = "{{abc}}, {{def}}, some text {{ghi}}, some other text {{jkl}}";
let regex = /{{(.*)}}/gi;
let result;
let indices = [];
let results = [];
while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
    indices.push(result.index);
    results.push(result[0]);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try escaping the `{`/`}`. i.e. `\{\{(.*)\}\}`

Comment: Also try `.*?`, i.e. `\{\{(.*?)\}\}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it: `\{\{(.*?)\}\}`

You need to escape the `}` via `\`, also set the non greedy operator `?`

See: https://regex101.com/r/F9xdgx/2